# Command Palette command to close the file browser panel.

Tags: visual-studio-code

The left panel (typically the file browser, but also extensions, debugging, etc) - takes up quite a bit of screen real estate.

I'm searched through the command palette - but I can't find a command to close it.

Is there one?

Comment: CTRL + B toggles the side-bar; http://donovanbrown.com/post/visual-studio-code-keyboard-shortcut-cheat-sheet

Comment: @spikey_richie thanks - that's exactly what I need. Post it as an answer.

Comment: Done. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> will toggle the side-bar.

For a full list of keyboard shortcuts, refer to http://donovanbrown.com/post/visual-studio-code-keyboard-shortcut-cheat-sheet